# Ionic keyboard not resizing content after closing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.2.3, browser 4.1.0, ios 4.4.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.1, (and 6 other plugins)

System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.2
   NodeJS     : v6.10.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 5.5.1
   OS         : macOS
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61

I'm losing my mind with this...

I have a particular screen where a user is asked to enter some numbers. So far so good. Keyboard pops up as expected and they're able to click done to close the keyboard. This is when everything turns to s**t.

For some very odd reason it's like the layout is moved up the page (at the height of the keyboard) but the the actual layout is still fine, in other words, when you click buttons at the button of the page you can't, but if you click where they would be if the keyboard was still visible it works, which is just crazy!

I've tried most stuff; 
 - this.content.resize() - doesn't seem to work
 - installing cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard - more on this below

```
<preference name="KeyboardResize" value="true" /> <!-- doesn't work -->
```

Here's the kicker, if you rotate the screen and rotate it back everything sorts itself out.

Installed cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard in the hope i could call content.resize() after it's closed. I can't even get my head around this plugin, half the documentation doesn't actually match the methods and i get "ERROR: Plugin 'Keyboard' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml."  - and yep that's the only keyboard plugin i have installed.

To be clear on how i'm installing the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard --save
import {Keyboard} from "@ionic-native/keyboard";
this.keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
```

Incidentally, if i use "Keyboard" from ionic-native instead then it starts to match the documentation more, ie,

```
this.keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false);
```

In any event, none it's works. I get "ERROR: Plugin 'Keyboard' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml."

I would happily post more code, but it's all very standard stuff - if there is something that i can provide to help diagnose please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Same issue; did you resolve it?